# Why can I set styles in JS without violating Content Security Policy's style-src 'self'?

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy

Setting `style-src` to `'self'` disables the use of inline styles via the `style` tag or the `style` attribute. This works as intended. Adding a `style` element via JS is also blocked.

But I was really surprised that I can still set properties of an `HTMLElement`'s `style` object. For example this doesn't trigger a CSP violation:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage = 'url("image.png")';
```

How does this then prevent attacks such as those described [here](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/disable-inline-styles.html) or [here](http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.co.at/2009/12/generic-cross-browser-cross-domain.html)?

Comment: Maybe this would be more appropriate for security.stackexchange.com or webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The URL "image.pn" is relative to self, what happens if you try an absolute URL that is on another domain?

Comment: @robertjd I just read up and in fact url() is subject to the `img-src` rule.

Comment: @user232986 For the unfamiliar, what is that rule?

Comment: @NateBarbettini CSP's `img-src` allows you to define from what sources images can be loaded.

Comment: Answers here explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608927/how-to-let-script-to-use-setattribute-style-without-breaking-csp

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because if you're already allowing script injection, style modification is the least of your worries.

The style elements and attributes are blocked to protect against malicious messing around that can be done *without* JS. If someone is modifying the DOM itself (not just presentation), that's far more serious anyway.

The second link you give is not relevant to this; the demo is no longer is up, but apparently what it was doing was linking to a referring page as if it was a stylesheet, and using the fact that some valid css had been planted in the referring page in two spots to treat the intervening text as an image URL. CSP isn't relevant there because the attack is from the other direction; The attacking link page would deliberately be set to allow loading of external stylesheets. (I don't think CSP header can be set on the HTTP response for a css file itself -- or other file being treated as CSS -- to disallow outside linking to it, although I could be wrong.)

Comment: "Presumably because if you're already allowing script injection, style modification is the least of your worries." is quite the accusation. Many libraries which are intentionally *included* on a site, have style manipulation within them to do what they do (like graphs, morphing, animations). So the question about why JS can still manipulate CSS (despite CSP restrictions on style-src) is valid.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I'm puzzled as to how you think that the fact that there are libraries that are intentionally included on sites is a refutation of my point.  The topic, explicitly, is injection by an attacker of malicious JS and what CSP can do to protect against it. There is no "accusation"—the case under discussion is already of malicious JS. I can see no scenario in which CSP restrictions that attempt to block style property manipulation from that would provide useful security (it's like window bars on a house already being burgled), but please present one if you have such a case in mind.